# Adding IPhone support for sqlLite DB

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, database-connection

I have an app that on need to get working on IPhone using Xamarin.

This is how it looks on my Android build:

```
using myMood.Data;
using myMood.Droid.Data;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]
namespace myMood.Droid.Data
{
    public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
    {
        public SQLite_Android() { }
        public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFileName = "myMood.db3";
            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFileName);
            var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

            return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

How would a "IPhone version" look for this?

Comment: it would be identical

Comment: Exactly the same... there is not need to use a Forms' Dependency service to do this as you are not using any native Android features in that code.

Comment: shouldnt I use "Library"-path for iOS?

Comment: @LasseEdsvik Your Connection object will differ with just the library path other then that it will be 100% same

Comment: @LasseEdsvik You can use a `switch` statement on the `Device.RuntimePlatform` in your .NetStd2.0 code https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-onplatform-runtimeplatform/ (note: If you really want to get technical `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` is not the correct location within your Android app's sandbox to store a database file even though it is the "closest" you can get using Mono's `SpecialFolder` and most Xamarin examples use it even though it is not based on the Android application filesystem layout described by the Android framework..., same is true for iOS...)

Comment: @LasseEdsvik added an example piece of code you can take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.Net Standard 2.0` and `Xamarin.Forms` you can directly achieve this in your Shared code something like below for the connection object

```
public static SQLiteAsyncConnection GetSQliteAsyncConnection()
    {
        string sqliteFileName = "myMood.db3";
        string dbPath = string.Empty;
        switch (Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.Android:
                string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                dbPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFileName);
                break;
            case Device.iOS:
                string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string libFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "Library");
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(libFolder))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(libFolder);
                }
                dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(libFolder, sqliteFileName);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        return conn;
    }
```

Comment: Since you are not using iOS specific calls, why not do it via Forms & NetStd2.0 code via a `switch` and `Device.RuntimePlatform` and skip the overhead of the dependency service?

Comment: @SushiHangover In that case do we even need the SQLite packages in our native projects?

Comment: @SushiHangover Done take a look

Comment: The long short answer can be yes and no  Depending upon the library type you are using and the version of Xamarin you are using, the Xamarin MSBuild build tasks, does not copy the "native" sub-dependancies of a NetStd2.0 library into the referencing (parent) project artifacts and thus you needed to add those packages in your native projects also. The newest versions of Xamarin seem to have ironed most of these issues and thus no, you can skip adding them to your native projects

Comment: That said, packages like ReactiveUI still fail during the Mono linking process and I'm still add it to the native projects... So not sure if it is an issue with some packages and their structure or the Xamarin's MSbuld tasks.... either way you find out really fast as the build will be broken...thus add the offending package to your native project... In terms of `sqlite-net-pcl`, it works fine only added to the NetStd  library project if using the latest versions of Xamarin (otherwise you would need to add it to the parent projects manually)

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks a lot, I learned a great deal lot from this, Thank you, You are like a role model!!